# Labeling the bars in a stacked BarChart

Tags: charts

I have the following data, which shows the number of events by day of the week (Sunday through Saturday) and hour of the day (00 through 23):

```
  data={<|0 -> 2200, 1 -> 300, 2 -> 100, 3 -> 50, 4 -> 150, 5 -> 1850, 
  6 -> 2450, 7 -> 2600, 8 -> 3050, 9 -> 4400, 10 -> 5550, 11 -> 8450, 
  12 -> 7650, 13 -> 7750, 14 -> 6750, 15 -> 6350, 16 -> 5250, 
  17 -> 4600, 18 -> 3700, 19 -> 2800, 20 -> 2700, 21 -> 2650, 
  22 -> 2500, 23 -> 1950|>, <|0 -> 1750, 1 -> 100, 4 -> 300, 
  5 -> 2500, 6 -> 3100, 7 -> 7350, 8 -> 10550, 9 -> 5900, 10 -> 7150, 
  11 -> 7350, 12 -> 7850, 13 -> 7500, 14 -> 6300, 15 -> 6900, 
  16 -> 9050, 17 -> 8150, 18 -> 3800, 19 -> 3000, 20 -> 2450, 
  21 -> 2450, 22 -> 2250, 23 -> 2150|>, <|0 -> 1450, 1 -> 50, 2 -> 50,
   4 -> 650, 5 -> 2500, 6 -> 3050, 7 -> 7700, 8 -> 10450, 9 -> 6400, 
  10 -> 8250, 11 -> 8050, 12 -> 8450, 13 -> 8250, 14 -> 7200, 
  15 -> 7800, 16 -> 9600, 17 -> 9100, 18 -> 4400, 19 -> 3200, 
  20 -> 2700, 21 -> 2550, 22 -> 2450, 23 -> 2200|>, <|0 -> 1650, 
  1 -> 150, 2 -> 100, 4 -> 750, 5 -> 2550, 6 -> 3050, 7 -> 7650, 
  8 -> 11300, 9 -> 7100, 10 -> 7750, 11 -> 9350, 12 -> 9250, 
  13 -> 8000, 14 -> 7950, 15 -> 7900, 16 -> 9500, 17 -> 9150, 
  18 -> 4900, 19 -> 3600, 20 -> 2950, 21 -> 2650, 22 -> 2550, 
  23 -> 2350|>, <|0 -> 1650, 1 -> 100, 2 -> 50, 3 -> 200, 4 -> 700, 
  5 -> 2550, 6 -> 3050, 7 -> 7350, 8 -> 11150, 9 -> 7200, 10 -> 8150, 
  11 -> 8150, 12 -> 8400, 13 -> 8100, 14 -> 7400, 15 -> 7900, 
  16 -> 9800, 17 -> 9100, 18 -> 4750, 19 -> 3550, 20 -> 2850, 
  21 -> 2750, 22 -> 2450, 23 -> 2100|>, <|0 -> 1800, 1 -> 50, 
  2 -> 100, 4 -> 900, 5 -> 2500, 6 -> 3050, 7 -> 7050, 8 -> 9800, 
  9 -> 6450, 10 -> 7750, 11 -> 8650, 12 -> 9350, 13 -> 8750, 
  14 -> 7450, 15 -> 8250, 16 -> 9100, 17 -> 9550, 18 -> 6100, 
  19 -> 4800, 20 -> 3800, 21 -> 3450, 22 -> 3100, 
  23 -> 2550|>, <|0 -> 2250, 1 -> 350, 2 -> 150, 3 -> 100, 4 -> 150, 
  5 -> 2250, 6 -> 2550, 7 -> 2500, 8 -> 3500, 9 -> 4350, 10 -> 5200, 
  11 -> 6900, 12 -> 6600, 13 -> 6600, 14 -> 6150, 15 -> 6350, 
  16 -> 5650, 17 -> 6200, 18 -> 5400, 19 -> 4850, 20 -> 3750, 
  21 -> 3850, 22 -> 3400, 23 -> 2950|>}
```

I've created the following stacked BarChart.  Each bar is a day of the week.
`ChartLabels->Automatic` labels the hours within each bar, but I'd also like to label the individual bars themselves as Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, etc.

```
BarChart[data, ChartLabels -> Automatic, 
 ChartLayout -> "Stacked", Joined -> True, ImageSize -> Large, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["Day of Week", Bold, 12, Blue], 
   Style["Volume", Bold, 12, Blue]}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

I.e., I'd like labels that are specifically associated with each bar, as seen below.  But if I use `ChartLabels` to specify the days of the week, I loose the hour labeling.  I want to keep both.  How do I do that?

```
dow = System`DateObjectDump`$DaysOfTheWeek;
BarChart[data, ChartLabels -> {dow, None}, 
 ChartLayout -> "Stacked", Joined -> True, ImageSize -> Large, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["Day of Week", Bold, 12, Blue], 
   Style["Volume", Bold, 12, Blue]}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: how do you get `distSort`?

Comment: Try `ChartLabels -> {dow, Automatic}`

Comment: @kglr Sorry, that was supposed to be `data` instead of `distSort`. I just corrected it.

Comment: @MelaGo  Beautiful, that works!

Comment: @MelaGo Why does `ChartLabels -> {dow, Automatic}` work, while `ChartLabels -> {Automatic, dow}`doesn't?

Comment: @theorist I think it's supposed to match the dimensions of the data. The first dimension is days, and the second dimension is hours. Example (modified from documentation for `ChartLabels`): `BarChart[{Range[3], Range[3]}, ChartLabels -> {{"1", "2"}, {"a", "b", "c"}}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
days = {Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday,
   Thursday, Friday, Saturday};

BarChart[data,
 ChartLabels -> {Placed[days, Axis], Automatic},
 ChartLayout -> "Stacked",
 Joined -> True,
 ImageSize -> Large,
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {None, Style["Volume", Bold, 12, Blue]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Bob, may I ask what does using`Placed[days, Axis]` in ChartLabels (`ChartLabels -> {Placed[days, Axis], Automatic}`) give us vs. the simpler syntax MelaGo offered (`ChartLabels -> {days, Automatic}`)? [They appear to give identical results.]  Is it just more options for placement?

Comment: It is just what came to mind. The shorter syntax is generally better unless you want the added clarity.